# There's a way to know if a View appeared for tabbar button has been tapped in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, view

I have two frame in ios, let's say View1 and View2. View1 contains a table view. When you tap a cell you're being redirected to View2 with a detail of what you tapped.
View1 is connected to a tabbar button, but if i tap the button after i went to View2, i'm returned to View2 and not View1, so i put inside View2 this code:

```
 -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 }
```

That is, when View2 disappear pop to View1, so in case i return back, using tabbar button i will be presented with View1

So far, so good.

Now, inside View2 there is a link presenting a MFMailComposeController so that you can send a mail. When i get back from mailing, the app crashes. It's totally right for viewWillDisappear is not distinguishing if View2 is disappearing for you're setting a mail or for you navigated to another View and the come back through tabbar. 
So, there is a way to distinguish if View2 is being presented for a tabbar button is being pressed or anything else happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex` inside `viewDidDisappear`. If the index is same as index of the view controller, then view controller need not be popped. When you switch tabs, the `selectedIndex` changes, so the view controller has to be popped.

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
      if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex != correctIndex )
      {
          [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
      }
}
```

Comment: pretty good idea but when i return from mailing, the selected index is still the same.

Comment: yes. it will change when you switch tabs. pop it when its not the same. check my updated answer @SashaGrievus